A confusion on Folland Real analysis p33
I'm reading Folland's Real Analysis and the below is from p33 which I have some questions: Does the h-intervals in the proposition include the unbounded ones? because if they do then $F$ is not defined on extended real numbers. if $\mu_0$ is a premeasure defined on $\mathcal{A}$ then what is its value on unbounded h-intervals?

The building blocks for our theory will be the left-open, right-closed
intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ - that is, sets of the form $(a, b]$ or $(a,
 \infty)$ or $\varnothing$, where $-\infty \leq a<b<\infty$. In this
section we shall refer to such sets as h-intervals (h for
"half-open"). Clearly the intersection of two h-intervals is an
h-interval, and the complement of an h-interval is an h-interval or
the disjoint union of two h-intervals. By Proposition 1.7, the
collection $\mathcal{A}$ of finite disjoint unions of $h$-intervals is
an algebra, and by Proposition 1.2 , the $\sigma$-algebra generated by
$\mathcal{A}$ is $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$.


1.15 Proposition. Let $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be increasing and right
continuous. If ( $\left.a_j, b_j\right]$ $(j=1,  \ldots, n)$ are
disjoint h-intervals, let $$  \mu_0\left(\bigcup_1^n\left(a_j, 
 b_j\right]\right)=\sum_1^n\left[F\left(b_j\right)-F\left(a_j\right)\right],
 $$ and let $\mu_0(\varnothing)=0$. Then $\mu_0$ is a premeasure on the
algebra $\mathcal{A}$.


$F$ is increasing, thus $F(-\infty)$ and $F(+\infty)$ are well-defined as extended real numbers by taking $F(\pm\infty) := \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} F(x)$, limits which exist thanks to the monotonicity.
More precisely, $F(-\infty)$ is either $-\infty$ or a real number, only one $a_j$ can be $-\infty$ due to the disjointness required, and $F(-\infty)$ is always preceded by a $-$ sign if it appears, so that $\mu$ is well-defined with values in $[0,+\infty]$.
